# Why doesn't this for loop populate the new dataframe properly?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a new data frame that calculates a score based upon survey answers. I can't seem to get the score data frame to populate correctly.

I have tried using a series of if else statements inside a for loop.

```
df <- rbind(c("Y", "no", "Often"), c("N", "yes", "always"), c("Y", "yes", 
    "never"))
score <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
t <- 1

for (t in nrow(df)) {

  if (df[t,1] == "Y") {
    score[t,1] <- 2
  } else if (df[t,2] == "yes") {
    score[t,2] <- 2
  } else if (df[t,3] == "always") {
    score[t,3] <- 2
  } else if (df[t,3] == "often") {
    score[t,3] <- 1
  }

  next

}
```

I am looking for the output to be:
2, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0

I am getting:
0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0

Comment: Try `for (t in 1:nrow(df))`.

Comment: that got a little closer, but still not the correct output. I am getting 2, 0, 0 / 0, 2, 0 / 2, 0, 0

Comment: ah, as soon as it hits a true, it moves on and doesn't do the remaining desired operations

Comment: what is another way to do this not using if else?

Comment: making them all if statements gets all the right outputs except the last one looking for the word "often"

Comment: as @willi7c7 pointed out you needed to (1) change them all to simple `if` statements, not `if ... else` and (2) there was also a typo in "often"

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple ways to bypass the loop and `if`/`else` structures using `dplyr::case_when` or `dplyr::recode`. Both of these functions provide vectorized ways of doing this replacement. All options here get the same output.

`dplyr::recode` takes a set of key-value pairs, with an optional default. It can also take a named list, unquoted with `!!!`, allowing you to save a lookup vector. Using `apply` instead of looping:

```r
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  recode(x, 
         Y = 2,
         yes = 2,
         always = 2,
         Often = 1,
         .default = 0)
}))
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  2  0  2
#> 2  0  2  2
#> 3  1  2  0

# with a lookup and !!!
lookup <- c(Y = 2, yes = 2, always = 2, Often = 1)

as.data.frame(apply(df, 1, function(x) recode(x, !!!lookup, .default = 0)))
```

You could also do those methods by recoding, making that into a matrix, then making that a data frame (similar to below).

Another option is `dplyr::case_when`, which is like a vectorized `switch` statement. One advantage here is that since you have multiple values being replaced with 2, you can use `%in%` instead of repeating yourself.

```r
as.data.frame(matrix(case_when(
  df %in% c("Y", "yes", "always") ~ 2,
  df == "Often" ~ 1,
  T ~ 0
), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
```

Finally, `dplyr::mutate_all` lets you use `recode` on all the columns after converting to a data frame.

```r
mutate_all(as.data.frame(df), recode, !!!lookup, .default = 0)
```

Comment: Very interesting! I will try that!

Comment: I must say that method is awesome! I love it!

Answer (score 2):

Because `t` was assigned the single value equal to `nrow(df)`, before entering the loop.

Here's a re-work of your (also a typo was corrected):

```
df <- rbind(c("Y", "no", "Often"), 
            c("N", "yes", "always"), 
            c("Y", "yes", "never"))
score <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))

for (t in 1:nrow(df)) {

  if (df[t,1] == "Y") {
    score[t,1] <- 2
  } 
  if (df[t,2] == "yes") {
    score[t,2] <- 2
  } 
  if (df[t,3] == "always") {
    score[t,3] <- 2
  } 
  if (df[t,3] == "Often") {
    score[t,3] <- 1
  }
}

score
  V1 V2 V3
1  2  0  1
2  0  2  2
3  2  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to convert to factor, set labels, then back to numeric.

```
matrix(as.numeric(as.character(
  factor(as.vector(df), 
         levels=c("always", "N", "never", "no", "Often", "Y", "yes"),
         labels=c(2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)))), 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    0    1
# [2,]    0    2    2
# [3,]    2    2    0
```

*Note:* If `df` is a data frame, not a matrix as in the example, we'll have to use `as.vector(as.matrix(df))`.

Comment: That's a good approach - unfortunately, as it is, it doesn't work if a data set doesn't contain all the seven different answers.

Comment: @Armali You're right, better to explicitly include also the levels. Updated.